# Eclipse RCP Fast View in Horizontal Orientation

Tags: eclipse, rcp, plugin.xml

I do know how to register a View in the Fast views bar within a RCP Eclipse application (using plugin.xml). It opens in Vertical orientation. Does anybody know how to tell this view to open in Horizontal orientation per default?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is available.
Already in 2004, it was mentioned in [bug 55830](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=55830):

We have no plans to expose the "horizontal/vertical" fastview option as API (since this concept might be removed in the future in favor of 2 resize sashes).

And the [2005 question](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/427782/) about the same feature went unanswered!

> I currently add a fast view to my perspective...

```
layout.addFastView(IConsoleConstants.ID_CONSOLE_VIEW, 0.35f);
```

> How can I programmatically set this view to default to a horizontal orientation?
>
> I assume this is not possible to do through the API?

THe current [`IPageLayout`](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/IPageLayout.html) doesn't seem to have any parameter for the orientation.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot for your answer. I guess I will have to check if I something is doable using plugin_customization.ini in order, maybe, to be able to set the default orientation for all the views in the fastbar. Thanks again.

Comment: @brice you are welcome. If you find anything, don't forget to publish an answer here: I am interested in what you can find.